# Help understanding Egyptian circle

Tags: mathematics, geometry, ancient-egypt

I was reading this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_geometry) searching for the Egyptian area of circle and there is a following picture there:

[image]

Trying to understand what is meant by this since it is under the "Area" section. I've read some other pieces regarding area of circle where Egyptians usually inscribed the circle inside of a square instead of drawing it like this. There is not much description on the page regarding this picture so just trying to make sense of it. Anyone have any idea what the picture is trying to explain?

Comment: Maybe useful Marshall Clagett, [Ancient Egyptian Science. A Source Book. Volume III Mathematics (1999)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Ancient_Egyptian_Science_Ancient_Egyptia/8c10QYoGa4UC) and Richard Gillings, [Mathematics in the Time of the Pharaohs (1972)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Mathematics_in_the_Time_of_the_Pharaohs/DoDMIVUIYFwC)